# SFTP Match multiple Users

Tags: ssh, user

I was trying to configure SFTP to a list of users, so I thought of creating a few blocks of "Match User" at "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" file.

Something like this:

```
# User A, B
Match User usera,userb
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   X11Forwarding no
   ChrootDirectory /mnt/shared/user_a_b

# User C
Match User userc
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   X11Forwarding no
   ChrootDirectory /mnt/shared/user_c
```

After that, I restarted SSH, logged out of my current user and found a first problem. Since I was using *usera* I locked myself out of SSH.
To solve that, fortunelly, I openned root's shell and removed usera from the first stanza.

```
Match User userb
```

Now, when I try to login *userb* or *userc* to SFTP I get the error below.

```
$ sftp userb@localhost
userb@localhost's password:
packet_write_wait: Connection to ::1 port 22: Broken pipe
Connection closed
```

Basically, the only difference between users is the ChrootDirectory.
How could I set up SFTP to multiple users with different folders?

Thank you

EDIT:

Looking at auth.log, the only messages shown are these:

```
sshd[18621]: Received signal 15; terminating.
sshd[21599]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
sshd[21599]: Server listening on :: port 22.
sshd[21665]: Accepted password for userb from ::1 port 50552 ssh2
sshd[21665]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user userb by (uid=0)
sshd[21700]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/mnt/shared/user_a_b"
sshd[21665]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user userb
```

I suppose the issue is with folder permissions, right?

My shared directorys permissions are these:

```
drwxrwx--T 20 root sambashare 4.0K May 11 16:09 user_a_b
drwxrwx--T  2 root sambashare 4.0K May 10 23:23 user_c
```

What I don't get is that userb is part of shared group:

```
$ groups userb
userb : userb users sambashare
```

Comment: Maybe set the path to the user's home directory in [/etc/passwd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of search I believe I have found a solution.
The issue was probably related to **SFTP chroot jail**. These might be the keywords for this problem.
I changed the chroot folder permission.

```
$ sudo chmod 2750 /mnt/shared/user_a_b
$ sudo chmod 2750 /mnt/shared/user_c
```

It seems chroot directory should not have group write permission. So, basically, I removed the write permission from chroot folder. They are now like this:

```
$ ll /mnt/shared/
drwxr-s--- 20 root sambashare 4.0K May 19 18:36 user_a_b
drwxr-s---  2 root sambashare 4.0K May 17 23:51 user_c
```

Now it's working fine. Thanks to everyone.